# Ionic 2 - ViewChild component is undefined

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

**THE SITUATION**:

From the app component I need to call a method in another component.

I read that `@ViewChild` is the way to do it.

But is not working in my case. I am getting the following error:

```
Cannot read property ... of undefined
```

**THE CODE**:

This for example is a simple test method inside the **HomePage component**:

```
testChild()
{
    alert('child working');
}
```

In the **app.component** I declare HomePage as the child component:

```
@ViewChild(HomePage) homePage: HomePage;
```

and then call the method from the constructor:

```
this.homePage.testChild();
```

It should work right?

Instead I am getting this error:

[image]

The problem is not that the view is not loaded yet.

I have tried also to call the child from a click event and got the same error.

**THE QUESTION**:

Why is the child component is undefined?

Do you know what am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you share more code about your app.component please? For example where do you call this method.

Comment: we are going to need to see your app.component html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> and then call the method from the constructor:

You need to call it in the `ngAfterViewInit` lifecycle hook. Angular will call the method.

```
import { AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component()
export class MyComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  @ViewChild(HomePage) homePage: HomePage;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.homePage.testChild();
  }
}
```

**See also:**

- [Lifecycle Hooks](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html)

Comment: thanks for reply. But is not working yet. Same error. No matter from where i call it the error is the same.

Comment: @johnnyfittizio is the home page component actually a component in the template? This is what `@ViewChild` is for

Comment: Yes HomePage is the root component and is imported in the app.component.  the app.html is a double menu where on the right menu there is a login form. the form is working, all the login is inside the app.component. Inside the app.component form submit function I will just need to call a method of the homePage component.

Comment: @johnnyfittizio But is the `<home>` component _directly_ in the template of the component you are trying to access it from?

Comment: Well i think no. Both component has their own template. But the Home template is called from the App component template: <ion-nav [root]="rootPage" #content></ion-nav>. So you say that Home component is not exactly the child of App component?

Comment: @johnnyfittizio It's not. Not at compilation time, the time that it needs to be. Ionic uses dynamic component loading. This will not work with `@ViewChild`. Maybe you should look into using a service to allows the components to communicate

Comment: Ok thanks. I will then mark your reply as correct. If you time can you please look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40841612/ionic-2-how-to-manage-global-variables I really cannot find a proper solution

Comment: @johnnyfittizio based on that post, try using a Subject, as [mentioned here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40469735/2587435)