# Can't resolve all parameters for User

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

I am trying to create a shared User data provider:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';


@Injectable()

export class User {

  public name: string;
  public email: string;
  public password: string;
  public birthday: string;
  public settings: Settings;
  public loggedIn: boolean;

  constructor({
                name = null, email = null, password = null, birthday = null,
                settings = new Settings(),loggedIn = false
              }: {
    name?: string; email?: string; password?: string; birthday?: string;
     settings?: Settings; loggedIn?: boolean;
  } = {}) {

    this.name = name;
    this.email = email;
    this.password = password;
    this.birthday = birthday;
    this.settings = settings;
    this.loggedIn = loggedIn;
  }

  /**
   * @returns {number} the user's age.
   */
  get age(): number {
    let age = Math.abs(Date.now() - new Date(this.birthday).getTime());
    return Math.floor(age * 3.16887646E-11);
  }

}

@Injectable()
export class Settings {
  notificationSettings: NotificationSettings;
  preferencesSettings: PreferencesSettings;

  constructor({
                notificationSettings = new NotificationSettings(),
                preferencesSettings = new PreferencesSettings()
              }: {
    notificationSettings?: NotificationSettings;
    preferencesSettings?: PreferencesSettings;
  } = {}) {

    this.notificationSettings = notificationSettings;
    this.preferencesSettings = preferencesSettings;
  }
}

@Injectable()
export class NotificationSettings {
  // TODO
}

@Injectable()
export class PreferencesSettings {
  // TODO
}
```

At the app component, I am declaring the provider, in order to make a user globally available.

When I am trying to build the project, I get a `Can't resolve all parameters for User: (?)` error.

The problem occurs because of the settings in the `User` constructor, but I am having a difficulty to find the error in my logic.

Comment: Check typo in your `constructor` and are you using `barrels`

Comment: I don't think that is injectable, or that it should be; it's just a data class. If you want to inject it, use an InjectionToken.

Comment: @Aravind the constructor doesn't seem to have any typo. Also I am not using barrels.

Comment: why you are using your class User as `@injector`?

Comment: @Aravind I am trying to implement something similar to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40841612/ionic-2-how-to-manage-global-variables

Comment: @jonrsharpe how would an injectionToken help?

Comment: You'd use it to specify which object you want injected. See https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html#!%23injection-token

Comment: So, basically you want to create a shared service to hold the information of the current logged in user, right?

Comment: @sebaferreras Exactly!

Comment: please take a look at the answer and let me know what do you think :)

Comment: @sebaferreras Great explanation, thank you. I will keep those things in mind next time.

Comment: Glad to hear that @Manos :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure of the exact scenario, but the problem with your code is that you need to know that one thing is a shared **service**, and another thing is a **model** that will be used in that service (and probably in some other services as well).

**Models should not be injectables**, they are just classes. Only services should. So in your case, we can start by creating the models of your app, and then we can add an `AccountService` to hold the instance of the user.

I've changed the name of the classes used as models just to avoid confusion (I think it's easier to know that something is a model if the name ends with -Model)

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

export class NotificationSettingsModel {
  // TODO
}

export class PreferencesSettingsModel {
  // TODO
}

export class SettingsModel {
  public notificationSettings: NotificationSettingsModel;
  public preferencesSettings: PreferencesSettingsModel;

  constructor() {
    this.notificationSettings = new NotificationSettingsModel();
    this.preferencesSettings = new PreferencesSettingsModel();
  }
}

export class UserModel {
    public name: string;
    public email: string;
    public password: string;
    public birthday: string;
    public settings: SettingsModel;

    constructor() {
        this.name = null;
        this.email = null;
        this.password = null;
        this.birthday = null;
        this.settings = new SettingsModel();
    }

    /**
    * @returns {number} the user's age.
    */
    get age(): number {
        let age = Math.abs(Date.now() - new Date(this.birthday).getTime());
        return Math.floor(age * 3.16887646E-11);
    }
}


@Injectable()
export class AccountService {

    public currentUser: UserModel = null;
    constructor() {}

    public isLoggedIn(): boolean {
        return this.currentUser !== null;
    }

}
```

After this, you'll need to add the `AccountService` in your main app module (or shared module). So for instance, you can add it in the `app.module.ts` file:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [...],
  imports: [...],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [...],
  providers: [AccountService] // <- Here!
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Then in your pages, just inject it and use it:

```
// imports...

@Component({...})
export class HomePage{

    constructor(public accountService: AccountService) {}

    public someMethod(): void {
      // You can access the properties
      // this.accountService.currentUser;

      // And also the methods: 
      // this.accountService.isLoggedIn();
    }

}
```